# how to configure same profile for every user in a organization

Tags: configuration, user-profile

I need to set the user variables and settings for every user in a domine when I am configuring the workstation for him.
the settings. are :Advanced performance options- visual effects for best performances 
2. Java Auto update option is to be disabled or unchecked
3.in Internet security sttings  under Download - Misclanious -DIsply Mixedcontent should be enable.
4.User envaironment variable should be TEMP =E:\temp

Answer (score 1):

Windows [Unattended](http://unattended.msfn.org/unattended.xp/) mode allows to customize such settings. A tool such as [nLite](http://www.nliteos.com/) can help.